# Record directory sizes on shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shell, automation

What would be the easiest way to record and store the sizes(and a timestamp) of a few chosen directories upon each shutdown - say in a .csv file.

Comment: I would use Powershell script to do this.

Comment: Yea... I figured it'd come down to this. I was just hoping a helpful soul already familiar with the API would come in and do in 30 seconds what would take me and hour of research.

Comment: What your asking wouldn't be 30 seconds of work for anyone.  Furthermore you should have done the hour of research BEFORE asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple... A search for '[PowerShell get folder size](https://www.google.com/?q=PowerShell%20get%20folder%20size)' and '[PowerShell append to csv](https://www.google.com/?q=PowerShell%20append%20to%20csv)' would get you there.

I'm too lazy right now to append to a CSV because it's kind of a pain (You'd think it would be easy, right? PowerShell is so quirky when it comes to CSVs...) I'd recommend keeping a few .txt files instead, especially since you don't seem to have any inkling to hack your way through this yourself.

I'll give you some clues from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156791.aspx).

```
(ls C:\Folder -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum / 1GB
```

That will snag the folder size (in GB) and all its subfolders/items.

Then simply [pipe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176927.aspx) it to:

```
Add-Content c:\totallynotpr0n_folder_size.txt
```

Kablam, you've got a .txt file with the folder size in it, so you can keep track of how big your 'photo collection' grows each night. Do this for each folder you want to keep track of and make a new .txt file for each.

I recommend using PowerShell ISE so it's convenient to test and save as a .ps1 file. Then you can run your script as a scheduled task (there's a bit of a snag with Execution Policy, you'll want to follow [this guide](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler) and pay special attention to the 'Set Argument' paragraph.)

Good luck!